# Nodejs: Spawn jar (non executable)

Tags: java, node.js, exec, noclassdeffounderror, spawn

I have a Java jar file, which is not executable(does not have a main method).
However I would like to invoke a particular class and its methods from my node.js application. I am currently using the below:

```
var child = require('child_process').spawn(
'java', ['-cp', "abc.jar", com.abc.ABCClass]
);
```

How now can I invoke the method in the ABCClass with appropriate arguments?
I currently get an exception such as below:

```
A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" 
Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer
```

Thanks in advance. I am looking for a solution to call the method in that class.

Comment: What happens when you run it in the command line?

Comment: If I run the same in command line I get
`Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)`

Comment: You could use vm like http://www.graalvm.org/ that supports js/java polyglot applications